# Evaluating $ \lim_{ (x, y) \to (0, 0 ) } \frac{ x-y }{ x^2 + y^2 }$ and $ \lim_{ (x, y) \to (0, 0) } y \log \left( x^2 + y^2 \right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

> How to calculate these?
>
> (i) $$ \lim_{ (x, y) \to (0, 0 ) } \frac{ x-y }{ x^2 + y^2 }$$
>
> (ii) $$ \lim_{ (x, y) \to (0, 0) } y \log \left( x^2 + y^2 \right)$$

My Attempt:

(i)

> If $y = x$, then we have
> $$
> \lim_{ (x, y) \to (0, 0 ) } \frac{ x-y }{ x^2 + y^2 } = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ x-x}{x^2 + x^2} = 0. 
> $$
> But for any $m \neq 1$, if we put $y = mx$, then
> $$
> \lim_{ (x, y) \to (0, 0 ) } \frac{ x-y }{ x^2 + y^2 } = \lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{ x - mx}{ x^2 + m^2 x^2} = \frac{ 1-m}{ 1 + m^2 } \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} = \infty. 
> $$
> So the limit in question fails to exist.

Am I right?

(ii)

> If we put $y = mx$, then
> $$
> \begin{align} 
> \lim_{ (x, y) \to (0, 0) }  y \log \left( x^2 + y^2 \right) &= \lim_{x \to 0} mx \log \left[ \left( 1 + m^2 \right) x^2 \right] \\ 
> &= m \lim_{ x \to 0} \big[ x \log \left( 1 + m^2 \right) + 2x \log x \big] \\
> &= 0 + 2m \lim_{x \to 0} x \log  x \\
> &= 2m \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \log x }{ \frac{1}{x} } \\
> &= 2m \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \frac{1}{x} }{ - \frac{1}{x^2 } } \\
> &= - 2m \lim_{ x \to 0} x \\
> &= 0.
> \end{align}
> $$

> On the other hand, if $y = mx^2$, then
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \lim_{ (x, y) \to (0, 0) } y \log \left( x^2 + y^2 \right) &= \lim_{x \to 0 } mx^2 \log \left( x^2 + m^2 x^4 \right) \\
> &= m \lim_{x \to 0} x^2 \log x^2 \ + \  m \lim_{x \to 0} \big[ x^2 \log \left( 1 + m^2 x^2 \right) \big] \\
> &= 2 m \lim_{ x \to 0} x^2 \log x \ + \  m \lim_{x \to 0} \big[ x^2 \log \left( 1 + m^2 x^2 \right) \big] \\
> &= 2m \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \log x }{ \frac{1}{x^2} } \ + \ m \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \log \left( 1+m^2 x^2 \right) }{ \frac{1}{x^2} } \\
> &= 2m \lim_{ x \to 0} \frac{ \frac{1}{x} }{ -\frac{2}{x^3} } \ + \ m \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \frac{ 2m^2 x }{1+m^2 x^2} }{ - \frac{2}{x^3} } \\
> &= -m \lim_{x \to 0} x^2 \ - \ m^3 \lim_{ x \to 0} \frac{ x^4 }{1 + m^2 x^2 } \\
> &= 0.
> \end{align}
> $$

> Thus one would guess that
> $$
> \lim_{ (x, y) \to (0, 0 ) } y \log \left( x^2 + y^2 \right) = 0.
> $$

Is this so? If so, then how to rigorously prove this?

Comment: The first is correct. The second: the limit is equal to zero, but the approach is not correct. You can use polar coordinates instead. The function becomes $r\sin(\varphi) \log(r^2).$ Then independently of $\varphi$ is the limit equal to $0.$

Answer (score 2):

The first one does not exist.

The second limit however exists. Note that in polar coordinates, we have

\begin{equation}
y\ln\left( x^{2} +y^{2}\right) =2r\sin \theta \ln( r) \tag{1}
\end{equation}

So we have

\begin{equation}
|y\ln\left( x^{2} +y^{2}\right) |=|2r\sin \theta \ln( r) |\leq 2|r\ln r| \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Can you finish now (using either chain rule or $\displaystyle \epsilon -\delta $ definition)?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. Let $(x_n, y_n) \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} (0,0)$. If beyond a certain $n_0$, $(x_n, y_n) = (0,0)$, then $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n \log ( f(x_n, y_n) ) =0$, obviously. Otherwise we can just remove the terms with $(x_n, y_n) = (0,0)$ from the sequence. Then $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n \log(f(x_n, y_n)) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log(f(x_n, y_n))}{f(x_n, y_n)} f(x_n, y_n) y_n = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (x_n^2+y_n^2)y_n = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Polar coordinate and squeeze theorem are enough for the second one $$-r\ln(r^2)\leq r \sin(\theta)\ln (r^2)\leq r\ln(r^2)$$